# Is there any possibility to understand participant emotions while doing Remote Testing?

Tags: usability

As you might be aware that, capturing or understanding participants body language, emotions, facial expressions while doing Usability Testing is very crucial. But, while doing "Remote Testing", obviously we cannot see the facial expressions of the participant.

So, did anyone of you face this challenge, if so, how did you handle this?

Comment: Depends on the testing environment, but could they use a camera to record themselves?

Comment: Generally, we use userzoom or some other tools to do remote testing. The participant is allowed to do this activity at his / her convenient time. So, recording is not possible. If we are watching remotely, the participant will share the screen.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't be 'so' remote**

I use the process whilst doing remote user testing and it works great:

1. Get your user on a video call (Google hangout works best)
2. Give them a quick intro into who you are what you are doing today
3. Get them onto your product
4. Explain that you test with 10+ people at a time and for duration of time they (the user) are using the product you (the tester) will not be on the call as you (the tester) will be doing what you are doing right now (introducing the process and getting them set up) with other customers. Also ask for permission to record the conversation
5. Tell them to when they are finished type into the chat "Finished" (works best in Google Hangouts)
6. Once they understand - turn off your camera and mute your self
7. If they have agreed to being recorded - start your recording - lookback.io is great tool of this
8. Observe your user
9. Once they type "Finished" wait a couple of seconds - then come back on the call and thank them for the time.

Comment: When we need to observe closely, we deal with only one participant, it could direct or remote testing. If we go with a huge number (10+) at a time like a survey, we engage something like "userzoom" or any other tool to get the statistics for us.

Regarding hangouts: Screen sharing is also vital during the remote testing since we need to observe user actions on the screen. If participant shares the screen, we cannot see him.